# Apache RequestHeader Directive in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, request-headers

I am trying to use the following apache configuration on a Godaddy shared hosting account:

```
<Files ~ ".*">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
RequestHeader unset Host
RequestHeader append Host mydomain.com
</IfModule>
</Files>
```

The above is contained in a .htaccess file.
In other words... For all files and paths set the request's host to mydomain.com

The above doesn't seem to work. I get a 500 error on Godaddy's servers.

Thanks muchly!

Comment: is there an error you are getting? you didn't exactly explain what the problem is with your approach.

Comment: Where’s the question? Have you tried just the `RequestHeader` directive to see if this module is available?

Comment: I've edited the post to include the following line: "The above doesn't seem to work. I get a 500 error on Godaddy's servers."

Comment: Why do you want this behavior anyway? Why don’t you just ignore the Host value?

Comment: I am attempting to use a rewrite rule to proxy the request to my other website aslo on Godaddy as follows:
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$  http://mydomain.net/app1/$1 [P,L]
However it appears the request is retaining the original Host and therefore no being routed to the website specified in the rewrite rule.

Comment: I rather think that your pattern is incorrect. If using mod_rewrite in a .htaccess file, the path prefix is being removed before applied to the pattern. Thereby “/foo/bar” is converted to “foo/bar” (if the .htaccess file is in the root “/”). So remove the leading slash from the pattern.

Comment: OMGoodness! I think u're right! I will make the modification when I get home! Thanks! Do you guys get paid for giving such good advice and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was provided by [Gumbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo) in the comments above

> I rather think that your pattern is
>   incorrect. If using mod_rewrite in a
>   .htaccess file, the path prefix is
>   being removed before applied to the
>   pattern. Thereby “/foo/bar” is
>   converted to “foo/bar” (if the
>   .htaccess file is in the root “/”). So
>   remove the leading slash from the
>   pattern. – Gumbo Feb 23 at 14:29